# How to generate a JAR with the source code in Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

How can I use Maven 2.2 to generate a JAR with the source code inside it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`<resources>` element](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources); nutshell:

```
<build>
<...>
<resources>
 <resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
 </resource>
 <resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
 </resource>
</resources>
<...>
</build>
```

*Edit:* Oh, I thought you meant you wanted a single jar with both normal jar contents and the source.

Answer (score 35):

```
mvn source:jar
```

This is using the source:jar plugin [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html)

[Usage documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: this only generates jar that contains source code, but without compiled classes

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what the OP wanted. Good answer, @stacker.

Answer (score 6):

To do this automatically as part of your build, configure the [maven-source-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html) to bind to the appropriate phase of your build:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will create an additional jar file with the `source` classifier, ie: `<your-artifact-name>-source.jar`